# jquery array of promises triggering resolved too soon

Tags: jquery, arrays, promise, deferred

i have a dynamic list of input boxes.  when button is clicked, each line item is sent to server to process and save to db.  when all of requests have returned, process is supposed to call the "finish".

i have this from various examples online:

```
var promises=[];
$("input").each(function(){
  $(promises).push(
    $.get("processRequest?value="+$(this).val(),
      function(){
        $("div ##div_"+i).html("done with input " + i);
      }
    );
  }
);

$.when.apply(promises).done(function() {
  alert('done!');
}
```

but the done triggers when the 1st get returns.   when the alert popup shows, i can still see some of the requests still haven't returned yet.

what am i missing here?

Comment: `.apply()` needs another parameter. Try `$.when.apply(null, promises)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing a `.each` result, rather than the promises. $.when waits for each promise in an array of promises to fulfill. Your condition is backwards, try:

```
 $("input").each(function(){
    promises.push($.get("processRequest?value="+this.value,
      function(){
        $("div ##div_"+i).html("done with input " + i);
      }
    )
  });
```

Or alternatively:

```
 var promises = $("input").map(function(e){ 
        return $.get("processRequest?value="+e.value,...);
 }).get();
```

As a side note, divs with incremental numeric IDs are usually indicative of a code design problem.

Comment: you get my vote just for calling out the terrible naming convention for the IDs.

Comment: my bad.  i copied my code wrong.  i am indeed doing push() inside of the each().


the divs are actually to tie each line item with an associated display output area.  input_0 goes with div_0.   what would be better?  i'm working with existing solution so redesigning the UI probably won't be possible but if i could do some small JQ code changes, i'd be open.

Comment: hmm.interesting.  i compared your code ben and noticed you used promises.push()   and i had used $(promises).push().      i changed it over to use the bare JS array object and it works good now.   thanks!

Comment: The OP also needs to use `$.when.apply($, promises);`, not `$.when.apply(promises);`